# me sale este error: NameError: name 'between_callback' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, hilos, class

Tengo este codigo pero no se porque no me no me reconoce la funcion **between_callback()**

```py
import discord, json, os
import datetime, random, time

#Para poner mensajes por tiempo
from core.modules.greetings import time_messege
import threading
import asyncio


class BotClient(discord.Client):

    @staticmethod
    def is_DMChannel(message: str) -> bool:
        """Verifica si es un mensaje proveniente es de un canal privado"""
        return isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel)


    def between_callback(args):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

        loop.run_until_complete(time_messege(args))
        loop.close()


    #Ese metodo se ejecuta automaticamente cada vez que el bot se enciende
    async def on_ready(self) -> None:

        print("Logged on as {0}!".format(self.user))

        #x = threading.Thread(target=time_messege) #Creo un thread independiente del main_thread
        #x.start()

        _thread = threading.Thread(target=between_callback, args=("some text"))
        _thread.start()
```

Pero me sale este error, no entiendo porque no me toma esta funcion

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 113, in on_ready
    _thread = threading.Thread(target=between_callback, args=("some text"))
NameError: name 'between_callback' is not defined
```

La verdad no estoy segura porque me tira eso, espero puedan ayudarme, estoy declarando mal alguna funcion?

---

Actualizacion:

Hice estos cambios de acuerdo a lo que me comentaron

```py
    def between_callback(self, args):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

        loop.run_until_complete(time_messege(args))
        loop.close()


    #Ese metodo se ejecuta automaticamente cada vez que el bot se enciende
    async def on_ready(self) -> None:

        print("Logged on as {0}!".format(self.user))

        #x = threading.Thread(target=time_messege) #Creo un thread independiente del main_thread
        #x.start()

        _thread = threading.Thread(target=self.between_callback, args=("some text"))
        _thread.start()
```

Pero me sale este error de los parametros

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\PC0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: between_callback() takes 2 positional arguments but 10 were given
```

A que se refiere con que toma 2 pero 10 son dados?

El code al que se llama oasea time_messege() es:

```py
import time, random, discord
from datetime import datetime


async def time_messege(args):

    alarmtime = "16:26"
    greeting_channel = bot.get_channel("814238156396298310")
    #channel = bot.get_channel = xxx

    while True:
      
        lcltime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')

        if lcltime == alarmtime:

            #aca pondria el code de detectar canal y enviar
            print("is time!")

            random_num = random.randint(1, 4)

            if answer_num == 1:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, como estan chic@s?")
            if answer_num == 2:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, Como va su dia? que me cuentan?")
            if answer_num == 3:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, Como va su dia? que andan haciendo?")
            elif answer_num == 4:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, como se encuentran?")

            await time.sleep(90)

        else:
            print("not yet")
            await time.sleep(10)
```

No se si esto es importante pero igual aclaro, puede que los 10 argumentos sean por la cadena de texto en args=("some text")  ?

Comment: Puedes ver esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645272/how-do-i-pass-an-async-function-to-a-thread-target-in-python) en ingles

Comment: La función `between_callbacks()` la has declarado dentro de la clase, por lo que no es una función normal, sino un método. Para referirte a ella desde dentro del objeto debes hacer `self.between_callbacks`. Observa además que  deberías declarar en ella un primer parámetro `self` o bien decorarla con `@staticmethod`.

Comment: @abulafia , gracias intente eso que me dijiste pero me salieron estos 2 errores de parametros, acabo de actualizar la pregunta ahi puse el nuevo code debajo.

Comment: Falta una coma en `args=("some text", )` Esa coma es la que marca que `args` sea una tupla de un solo elemento. Sin esa coma, es como si no hubieras puesto paréntesis, y por tanto `args="some text"`. Precisamente la cadena "some text" tiene nueve caracteres, que son los diez parámetros (junto con `self`) que se están intentando pasar a la función (python trata el valor de `args` como un iterable e itera sobre él para crear los parámetros a pasar)

Comment: @abulafia muchas gracias por la ayuda